# Temporarily change locale settings

Tags: r, locale, strptime

### Actual question

How can I **temporarily** change/specify the locale settings to be used for certain function calls (e.g. `strptime()`)?

### Background

I just ran the following [`rvest`](https://github.com/hadley/rvest) demo:

`demo("tripadvisor", package = "rvest")`

When it comes to the part where the dates are to be scraped, I run into some problems that most likely are caused by my locale settings: the dates are in an US american format while I'm on a German locale:

```
require("rvest")
url <- "http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g37209-d1762915-Reviews-JW_Marriott_Indianapolis-Indianapolis_Indiana.html"

reviews <- url %>%
  html() %>%
  html_nodes("#REVIEWS .innerBubble")

date <- reviews %>%
  html_node(".rating .ratingDate") %>%
  html_attr("title")
> date
 [1] "December 9, 2014" "December 9, 2014" "December 8, 2014" "December 8, 2014"
 [5] "December 6, 2014" "December 5, 2014" "December 5, 2014" "December 3, 2014"
 [9] "December 3, 2014" "December 3, 2014"
```

Based on this output, I would use the following format: `%B %e, %Y` (or `%B%e, %Y` depending on what "with a leading space for a single-digit number" actually means WRT to the leading space; see `?strptime`).

Yet, both fails:

```
strptime(date, "%B %e, %Y")
strptime(date, "%B%e, %Y")
```

I suppose it's due to the fact that `%B` expects the month names to be in German instead of English:

> Full month name in the current locale. (Also matches abbreviated name on input.)

---

### EDIT

`Sys.setlocale()` let's you change your locale settings. But it seems that it's not possible to do so after a function relying on locale settings has been called. I.e., you need to start with a fresh R session in order for the locale change to take effect. This makes **temporary** changes a bit cumbersome. Any ideas how to work around this?

This is my locale:

```
> Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_ALL")
[1] "LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252;LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252;LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252"
```

When I change it **before** running `strptime()` for the first time, everything works just fine:

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "us")
> strptime(date, "%B %e, %Y")
 [1] "2014-12-09 CET" "2014-12-09 CET" "2014-12-08 CET" "2014-12-08 CET" "2014-12-06 CET"
 [6] "2014-12-05 CET" "2014-12-05 CET" "2014-12-03 CET" "2014-12-03 CET" "2014-12-03 CET"
```

However, if I change it **after** having run `stptime()`, the change does not seem to be recognized

```
> Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "German")
[1] "LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252;LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252;LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252"
> strptime(date, "%B %e, %Y")
 [1] "2014-12-09 CET" "2014-12-09 CET" "2014-12-08 CET" "2014-12-08 CET" "2014-12-06 CET"
 [6] "2014-12-05 CET" "2014-12-05 CET" "2014-12-03 CET" "2014-12-03 CET" "2014-12-03 CET"
```

This should actually result in a vector of `NA`s if the change back to a German locale had been carried out.

Comment: Use `Sys.getlocale()` and `Sys.setlocale()`.  See `?locales`

Comment: Thanks, just saw that as well. But a change of locale settings only seems to work before any function relying on that has been called. So that pretty much rules out temporary-only changes, right? Any idea how to work around that?

Comment: Can you turn that into a reproducible example?

Comment: I forgot the computation of `reviews`. Should be reproducible now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`parse_date_time()` from the [`lubridate`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html) package is what you are looking for. It has an explicit `locale` option for parsing strings according to a specific locale.

```
parse_date_time(date, orders = "B d, Y", locale = "us")
```

gives you:

```
[1] "2016-02-26 UTC" "2016-02-26 UTC" "2016-02-26 UTC" "2016-02-24 UTC" "2016-02-23 UTC" "2016-02-21 UTC"
[7] "2016-02-21 UTC" "2016-02-21 UTC" "2016-02-20 UTC" "2016-02-20 UTC"
```

Note that you give the parsing format without leading `%`as you would in `strptime()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `readr::locale("en")` inside `readr::parse_date()`

```
  readr::parse_date(date, format = "%B %e, %Y", 
              # vector of strings to be interpreted as missing values:
                na = c("", "NA"), 
                locale = readr::locale("en"), 
              # to trim leading and trailing whitespaces:
                trim_ws = TRUE)
```

From the docs: *"The locale controls defaults that vary from place to place. The default locale is US-centric (like R), but you can use locale() to create your own locale that controls things like the default time zone, encoding, decimal mark, big mark, and day/month names."*